# Is using a password to ssh into one computer where my ssh keys are stored and then using those keys unsafe?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I know that it is much safer to use ssh keys than to use username and passwords.  So my question is this:

If I have to ssh into a a few servers from a box that I have never used before (so that I have to use my username and password), is it safe for me to just ssh into one computer and then use that computer (which would have all of my ssh keys stored on it) to hop to the other computers?

Does this provide any advantages?

Answer (score 2):

The strength of your computer system(s) is only as strong as the weakest link.

Using SSH keys is a far stronger approach than username/password, but if username and password is still an option then that is your weakest link. If you were to disable password authentication on all the other computers, it would be marginally safer only due to the fact that your exposure is now limited to one computer that is vulnerable to a brute force password attack.

If you have a set of trusted computers (meaning you are the only person that has root access to this box), I would recommend installing your public key on each of these computers, and then using what's called "SSH Agent Forwarding" to allow your starting computer to SSH and authenticate with every computer along the way. This way, your starting computer will act as the master and provide credentials as necessary, unfortunately if you're using a computer that is 'new' you don't have this luxury.

Even if you aren't using Ubuntu, this is a good article to read: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Disable_Password_Authentication

I haven't tried this myself, but 2-factor auth may be a good solution to your password/foreign computer use-case: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication

At the very least I would recommend you to use a password manager (such as mSecure) and cryptographically secure random generated password of sizeable length.

Disclaimer: I'm not computer security expert, I've just picked up a thing or two over the years.